# Hint and Text in editText at same time

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, hint

I just need an editText in which i can set Text and hint at the same time.
e.g i want user to enter in editText string like user#1234
in this string user# should be text after that numbers will vary so that 1234 should be show as hint when user try to enter cursor will go after # and 1234 hint will gone when user type a character.

Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: down voter can you tell me the reason

Comment: haha you seriously think he'll reopen the thread?

Comment: Just wanna ask the mistake so that next time i ll more carefull

Comment: I'm guessing the bad English, and maybe the text formatting.

Comment: Please format it and gain 2 upvote Vucko :D

Comment: Let me compensate your down vote :P Just coz this is a legit question. You might have received a negative vote coz of your bad English. Nevermind thats okay.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to achieved this with bit of tricks and playing with `margin` and `padding`

This is what I did

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="user#" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="1234"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you out

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the Android's default `EditText` but if want to achieve this any how, you will have to work a bit.

You can use this library called [Masked-EditText](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext). Read the documentation and understand how you can use it to solve your purpose. Hope that helps.

[EDIT]

I've got one more trick that you can definitely use. Implement an `onChangeListener` on the edit text. Every time it is called, run a function. The function should get the text in the `editText` and get the substring (first 5 char). If the substring matches "user#" then do not do anything. Else replace the text in editText with "user#". Easy hah!

Comment: @KhizarHayat I have edit my answer. Check the new one.

Comment: i think you didn't get my question sorry for bad english

Comment: When user see my editText it will show user# as string and next to if 1234 as hint DIM COLOR hint .

Comment: @KhizarHayat ok. For that you have to use the library. Anyways, if my answer helps. Dont forget to upvote and/or mark it right.

Comment: Thanks for your time i ll see that library if it helps me ill accept

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways

`#1`

Place an Image with user# as `drawableLeft` to your `EditText`

`#2`

Use a `RelativeLayout` to place a `TextView` and `EditText` one above the other so that it shows text in `TextView` as hint in `EditText` as below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="user#"
    android:textColor="#aaaaaaaa"
    android:textSize="30dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:textSize="30dip">

</EditText>
```

Comment: If user # will be image then user can delete it , so it will not the choice.
If we put textView before editText then the underline of editText will not go under the textView
Right?

Comment: user# will be a drawable, how can user delete it ?

and 

in case of underline, provide an underline at the bottom on relative layout

Comment: oh sorry typo just wanna said user can't delete it.

User can delete it thats why we dont put it as drawable

Comment: that underline drawable will not same as editText custom underline drawable which is uplift from both edges

Comment: that depends on your creativity :P