# Hide Hint after EditText not null

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I just want to remove or hide the hint after the `EditText` being filled

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_login_email"
                    android:hint="Masukkan email anda"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="Email@email.com"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_round_light" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: remove android:text="Email@email.com"

Comment: you should use only one at a time, either text or hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153633/hint-and-text-in-edittext-at-same-time#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=This%20is%20not%20possible%20in,this%20library%20called%20Masked%2DEditText.

Comment: hint visibility depends on edit text listeners.  Means, it will only come in action when u are starting typing in edittext

Comment: you can also write a TextChangeListener for your EditText and check for the content. if the content of the editText is blank, setHint to whatever you want. if the content of the EditText is not blank, setHint to blank. Although if you are in android studio the hint is only shown when the EditText is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in activity**

```
override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            checkFieldsForEmptyValues()
            if (et_login_email.text!!.isNotEmpty()){ txt_email.hint="" } else txt_email.hint ="Masukkan email anda"
            if (et_login_password.text!!.isNotEmpty()){txt_password.hint=""} else txt_password.hint ="Masukkan password anda"
        }
```

**in XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/txt_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_login_email"
                        android:hint="Masukkan email anda"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_round_light" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```